# bash error: cannot execute binary file

Tags: bash, ssh

Why when I run the command

```
gnome-terminal -e "ssh -t sv \"cd ~/tmp/perl_libs/bin; bash /usr/bin/tail -f ~/open; echo 'YES'; exec $SHELL\""`
```

I got

```
/usr/bin/tail: cannot execute binary file
```

Comment: The `tail -f` is unlikely to exit, so your YES will never get printed and your target `$SHELL` won't be run. Perhaps you intend just to show the last few lines on the file, in which case omit the `-f`.

Comment: I know. The `bash -i` command prevents that. So I may CTRL+C to exit from `tail -f`. The question were 'why I can not run command with bash' and I get sharp answer

Comment: I see no sharp answers. You have one answer that explains how to fix the problem you're seeing. I was concerned about your `tail -f`, and warned you of the issue. You're happy with using Ctrl/C to end the `tail -f` process, so that's fine.

Comment: I get this error because `tail` is `Not a bash script`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need to is remove the bash in front of the tail.

As shown in

```
file /usr/bin/tail
/usr/bin/tail: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.4, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped
```

tail is a ELF file. Not a bash script.

Comment: Or, maybe, add `-c` bash option?