# Stop command in ssh session without exiting ssh

Tags: ssh, scripting, git

I have an ssh session and I'm running a script. 
I want to terminate the script without exiting the ssh session. 
If I run the script in a local PC, I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
and the script stops, while if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in remote session I close the ssh session itself (and also the script in this case). 
How can I stop the script in remote shell without interrupting the ssh connection?

I connect with the usual `ssh user@ip` command,
in a standard Ubuntu distribution, using the Git Bash from Windows.

In my Windows client the `.ssh/config` is as follows:

```
Host 192.168.XXX.YYY
  HostName 192.168.XXX.YYY
  User auser
  ForwardAgent yes

Host 192.168.XXX.ZZZ
  HostName 192.168.XXX.ZZZ
  User auser
```

They are not related to the remote server that I'm using.

Comment: What about `CTRL-Z` to put it into the background, then kill it? Although I am not sure why `CTRL-C` would kill the ssh session.

Comment: It's strange that Ctrl-C closes the ssh session. I never experienced this, pressing Ctrl-C in a ssh session always worked correctly for me, ie. did break the command running in the ssh session, but didn't exit the session. You must have configured something in a quite nonstandard way...

Comment: What exact local command (`ssh …`) do you use to connect? Does the command give you an interactive shell and then you run the script by hand? How exactly do you run it? Are there any custom settings in your (local) `~/.ssh/config` and/or `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` that apply to the connection? What is your local OS? What is the remote OS? Please [edit] the question and be specific.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I connect to remote server by using `ssh user@ip`, then I go manually to the folder where the python script is and I run it with `python3 myscript.py`. At this point the script is running, and if I try to stop it with Ctrl+C the session ends.

Comment: You say you logged into the shell and then started the script, its easy to write an example (with either shell or python) to show this is not normal behavior. Sounds to me like maybe that `myscript.py` is doing something in response to KeyboardInterrupt or a Ctrl-C INT signal, like killing the parent process.

Answer (score 5):

I got same behavior after installed Git for Windows 2.35.1.2.

I can avoid it after downgrade to version 2.34.1 from [here](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.34.1.windows.1).

Comment: I have the same behavior  on  version 2.38.1.windows.1. I find it working fine on v2.32.0, but I like your version (2.34.1) more. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this today as well — it appears to be a bug in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> handling with the bundled `/usr/bin/ssh` in Git for Windows.  Within Git bash, using its pre-packaged `ssh` the session would terminate when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, rather than sending that to the remote session to interrupt what was running there.  However, if I ran `/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> behaved as expected.  You can see which `ssh` is executing by typing `which ssh` in the bash session.

I corrected the problem by re-installing Git for Windows v2.35.1.2 — deselect the "Show only new options" checkbox so you can reconfigure everything, and as you install one of the options will be "Use external OpenSSH".  You must already have OpenSSH installed on your Windows system for this to work, of course — you can do that on a Windows 10/11 box by going to Settings→Apps→Optional Features→Add An Optional Feature and selecting the "OpenSSH Client".

Update:  I also reported the issue and it has been fixed in the latest snapshot.  So if you'd prefer to remain on the bundled `ssh` it should be fixed in the next release.

Comment: I have the same behavior on version 2.38.1.windows.1. So it is not fixed yet. I also tried your suggestion with "Use external OpenSSH" - it did not help, but make it worse, it is not only throwing me out on <ctrl>+<c>, but also does not show half a characters in the command line. What was the latest version when you see it was working?

Answer (score 0):

**gitbash** is glitchy indeed on this matter. Try `Windows PowerShell`. It is waking fine.